# Deploy Hyperledger febric blockchain code on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, devops, blockchain, amazon-eks

I want to deploy the hyperledger code on kuberenetes so want to check if someone have any experience how we can deploy this on kubernetes.

Comment: Do you have any special requirements or you just want to deploy to check your code? Did you see [this guide](https://www.hyperledger.org/blog/2018/11/15/how-to-deploy-hyperledger-fabric-on-kubernetes-part-ii)?

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, I have a code that are running on docker compose in which I have org1,org2 ,Orders and 4 peers. And now the issue is they have created the peer link like peer0.org1.blockchain.com and when I am running this in kubernetes I can not mention this dns name in manifest because of this ". dot" I need to use " hyphen -" in the dns and we have TLS certificate on that I am getting an error. So if you have any idea how will I do this in kubernetes do let me know

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem as you when I try to deploy fabric on kubernetes,and I have sloved it,I push it to my github, https://github.com/iamlzw/byfn-on-k8s ,

because kubernetes DNS standard,you cant use peer0.org1.example.com as your service name,so I define peer0-org1 as my service name,but the CN of my peer certificate is "peer0.org1.example.com",that means I have to concat peer with domain name "peer0-org1:7051",and I will meet "tls:bad certificate" error, if concat peer with domain name "peer0.org1.example.com",that means I have to link "peer0.org1.example.com" to the pod IP of peer on k8s DNS,but I dont know how to do this.

so how to solve the problem you raised in the comments:

- if you concat to peer on linux terminal,you can modify `/etc/hosts` to link "peer0.org1.example.com" to node IP which your peer is run(and your peer service is run with NODEPORT type), I use this method.
- if you concat to peer with cli container which is deploy on kubernetes pods,and you have set SAN on your peer certificat,you can set cli env CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0,and you can concat with peer use peer0:7051,you will concat success, you can reference [https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-ssl-san/#:~:text=The%20Subject%20Alternative%20Name%20(SAN)%20is%20an%20extension%20to%20the,use%20of%20the%20common%20name](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-ssl-san/#:%7E:text=The%20Subject%20Alternative%20Name%20(SAN)%20is%20an%20extension%20to%20the,use%20of%20the%20common%20name) 。
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try **FabDep** tool:
https://www.fabricdeployer.com/

Also, depend version of HLF you use - you can try **Hyperledger Cello**:
https://github.com/hyperledger/cello/tree/release-0.9.0-h3c

Also you can try
**blockchain-automation-framework** :

https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/blockchain-automation-framework/tree/master/platforms/hyperledger-fabric/configuration